# Triggering alert from Python on browser through Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

I have a server running Python code, (JupyterHub), and we're adding more features. I have a python function which is fired every 30 seconds on server side, and I have been actively searching for a simple way of triggering a simple Javascript alert on some server event.

Most of the previous questions provide answers which require to run a separate server exclusively for this. This question is about sending a notification when a server is already running. Pubnub, Tornado seem too complicated with not much of documentation.

Thanks !

Comment: In order for your JS client to receive a notification, it needs to be listening to the server, and the modern way to set up such a connection is via [web sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). Here's a [popular websocket server](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-server/0.4) package

Comment: Thanks @wilusdaman - that was quick. I am aware of websockets, but I am not sure if they'd be helpful in this case. I want my client side (javascript) to continuously sniff for any messages, and I need the python function to send message to it

Comment: Gotcha. What you're describing here is a simple polling system. You could just add a `/notifications` endpoint to your server that responds to requests with a list of all active notifications, then, in the client, hit that endpoint on some set interval